# How to check a Storm topology is loaded and up and running in Java

Tags: java, testing, apache-storm, topology

How can you check if a actual Storm topology has been loaded and running by Storm, to enable testing it on it. As the performing integration tests will be required to wait until the topology is running before starting the logic of the test. On local cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [storm command line interface](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Command-line-client.html) or use the Java client API directly. For example:

```
NimbusClient nimbusClient = new NimbusClient(conf, nimbusHost, nimbusPort, 30000);
List<TopologySummary> topologies = nimbusClient.getClient().getClusterInfo().get_topologies();
```

Comment: Does a LocalCluster have a nimbus running for the client to find? What would the port be? The standard 6627?